# How to implement REST in IBM Cast Iron?

Tags: json, rest

I am trying to create a REST services using IBM Cast Iron 6.3.0.1. I can use Read JSON or Write JSON node. But don;t know how to use them. Please let me know if anyone know about it.

http://blog.conexus-inc.com/2013/02/FR001.html
The link which i have searched so far. But need practical explanation to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this source can help [Using JSON in WebSphere Cast Iron, Part 3: Designing JSON-based REST APIs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1307_ramesh3/1307_ramesh3.html)

For example, first activity in your orchestration is "Http Request" where you should set input and output parameters from you GET or POST action. After that if you use POST you should implement "Read JSON" activity where you can map body on variables. Some processing after that may be using database as service or smth else. When you want to write response you should use "Write JSON" activity where you can map data for waiting result. Also don't forget set Content-Type for data using additional variable in httpheader with default value like "application/json" for example.

I believe that's help.